# Nginx, Rails reverse proxy raising 403 Forbidden

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, passenger

I am testing reverse proxy with Nginx+Passenger on OSX localhost

my nginx.conf is as simple as :

```
    #user  nobody;
    worker_processes  1;

    events {
        worker_connections  1024;
    }


    http {
        include       mime.types;
        default_type  application/octet-stream;

        sendfile        on;
        #tcp_nopush     on;

        keepalive_timeout  65;

        server {
            listen       80;
            server_name  localhost;
            location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8081/;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            }       
            location /simpleapp {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            }
        }
        server {
          listen 8081;
          server_name bayoo.website.local;
          root /Users/bayoo/Sites;
          index  index.html index.htm;
       }
        server {
          listen 3000;
          server_name simpleapp.local;
          root /Users/bayoo/Developpement/RAILS-41/simpleapp/public;
          passenger_enabled on;
       }

    }
```

127.0.0.1 simpleapp.local was added into /etc/hosts

when trying urls in my browser :
 //localhost ( proxy to => bayoo.website.local ) OK
 //bayoo.website.local    OK
but
 //localhost/simpleapp  => 403 Forbidden  , no info in error.log
and
 //simpleapp.local   does not display anything , seems to be locked

what could be wrong in my nginx config ?   I already tested the rails server alone :

```
        server {
          listen 3000;
          server_name simpleapp.local;
          root /Users/bayoo/Developpement/RAILS-41/simpleapp/public;
          passenger_enabled on;
       }
```

and it runs fine

Comment: AFAIK port 80 can only be used as root, you sure that the config properly binds to it? what is curl -I saying for that?

Comment: got it ...error in config ... working fine now

Comment: So what was the error? It would be nice if you could add it as an answer and accept it.